# .ajax() is triggering twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have displayed data using ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajs/index",
type: "GET",
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(data) {  
  var output="";
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
           output+="name:"+data[i].name
           +"<input type='button' class='delete' value='Delete'  data-id=" + data[i].id + "><br>"

     }
     $("#result").html(output); 
    }   //success function closed
});  //ajax call closed

   // when delete button is clicked.
           $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
                 var id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajs/"+id,
                    type: "delete", 
                    //data: "22",       
                    //dataType: "html",
                    success:function(data) { 
                        alert("success")
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("error")
                    }
                }); // delete  ajax() closed
                return false;
           });//delete click() closed
```

I have set of records displayed with each record having a delete button. When I click on that button the above function should be called. When I see my console it is triggering twice. First it is displaying `deleting ajs/idno.` and then it is showing `ajs/idno. 404 not found` error.

And the worst thing is even after deleting the record it is showing error message. It is not showing success message.

Comment: you seem to have more than one button with class `delete`

Comment: We'll need the HTML markup, but you it possibly be that you have assigned the `.delete` class to multiple nested DOM elements?

Comment: Or binding `click` multiple times.

Comment: As told, multiple binds may occur since you writing this inside ajax call. Write bind even outside it.

Comment: even if i write function outside ajax it is showing same thing

Comment: Please update what have you updated in your code after writing bind outside.

Comment: You are not closing the `ajs/index` ajax. Where does it stop ?

Comment: how to close ajs/index

Comment: Ok, so your `click` event isn't called in the `ajs/index` ajax. Then I don't know, look carefully if you're not stacking the `click` event on the `.delete` class.

Comment: actually i am working on rails application ajs/index means ajs is a controller and index is a action in that controller.

Comment: I don't know rails. Maybe you should create a new post more specific, because on what we can see, your JS is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting the `click` event each time the `ajs/index` is called.

You should put the `click` event outside of this ajax and write it like :

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajs/" + id,
        type: "delete", 
        success: function(data) { 
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    }); // delete  ajax() closed
    return false;
}); //delete click() closed
```

If the element with the `.delete` class is created dynamically, it'll work.

Comment: This is weird, I made it work a couple of times. Are you sure the event is set ?

Comment: ok. i am using this code in rails may be something is going wrong in other files. I am new to rails this is my first application .

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
$(".delete").unbind("click");
```

before attach event to $(".delete").